# How to use image tag in body of html instead of loading image from css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I am reloading the div every `10 seconds` without reloading the whole page. And also when refresh happens, it greys out my div and show the refresh image and after refresh is done, it loads the data in my div table and it is working fine.

Below is the refresh image I am using -

[image].

**Problem Statement:-**

Below is my JSP file `(dataInfo.jsp)` and I am reloading the div `container` every 10 seconds without reloading the full page.

```
<body>
    <div id='headerDivDash'>
        <h1 id='topHeaderDash'>
          <!-- some image here -->
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="vertical-list" style='display: block; list-style-type: none;'>
        <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
            <a href="_blank"><li>Test 1</li></a>
            <br />
            <a href="_blank"><li>Test 2</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- just need to reload this div, other div should be intact without getting appended -->
    <div class="container">

    </div>
    <div class="footer">Some Value Here</div>
</body>
```

Now below is the jquery script I am using to load the `div container` every 10 seconds and it works fine. I am able to see the refresh image and it also greys out so everything is working good so far.

```
// Create a refresh function:
function refresh(){
    // SHOW overlay
    $('#overlay').show();
    // Retrieve data:
    $.ajax({
        url: 'dataInfo.jsp',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            // onSuccess take only the container content
            var content =  $($.parseHTML(data)).filter(".container"); 
            //Replace content inside the div
            $('.container').replaceWith(content);
            // HIDE the overlay:
            $('#overlay').hide();
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Create overlay and append to body:
    $('<div id="overlay"/>').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: '100%',
        height: $(window).height() + 'px',
        opacity:0.4, 
        background: 'lightgray url(http://bradsknutson.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/page-loader.gif) no-repeat center'
    }).hide().appendTo('body');

    // Execute refresh with interval:
    setInterval(refresh, 1 * 1000);
});
```

Now as you see above, I have hardcoded the url for image. If I deploy my code in the production, then it will block this url because of firewall so somehow I need to load this image from my local folder in the project.

My directory structure is like this -

```
webapp/
|-- resources/
|   +-- img/
|           page-loader.gif
+- WEB-INF/
  +-- views/
        dataInfo.jsp
```

I tried using the path like this `background: 'lightgray url("/testweb/src/main/webapp/resources/img/page-loader.gif") no-repeat center'` it doesn't work that way also somehow.

So my question is - Is there any way I can rewrite the `overlay div` in my above jquery in the body of html somehow? Then I can use image tag which will work for me for sure.

```
<img src="page-loader.gif" />
```

Comment: Are you asking for the syntax of an img tag? `<img src='path' />`

Comment: @developerwjk: Obviously not.. I am not sure how do I rewrite the overlay div in such a way so that instead of loading the image in css from the url, I would like to use image tag where I can specify the path of image from local folder which is working fine for me in showing other images. See my updated last line in the question

Comment: It looks like your path is the local drive path, if your using it in javascript shouldn't it be relative to the website? "/resources/img/page-loader.gif"?

Comment: I have tried this as well `background: 'lightgray url(/resources/img/page-loader.gif) no-repeat center'`.. Doesn't work somehow for me..

Comment: If all else fails, why not use a data url?

Comment: Where is page-loader.gif located on the web server?

Comment: Try with a dot. `./resources/img/page-loader.gif` or double dot `../resources/img/page-loader.gif`

Comment: what about 'lightgray url( + document.domain + /resources/img/page-loader.gif) ?

Comment: Just add it to the end of the `<body>` tag with `display:none` style and remove the code from the `$(document).ready` function.

Comment: @vorrtex: That's what I am looking for. Can you provide an example for that which i can try out on my end if possible?

Comment: NB - if the image isn't loading when you put it in place via a CSS property, the image won't load as an image tag with the exact same URL. I think you're attacking the wrong problem -- using CSS to place the image is not different from the HTML tag, from a network access perspective.

Comment: @Chris: I am able to load that image from img tag in the body of an html and it works fine. I have some images which are working fine as well. And that's why in my question I asked if I can rewrite this thing in the body where I can provide img tag so that I don't need to load image from css. I load the image using img tag like this in our company and it works fine `<res:img class="testL" value="${res.img.local.img['page-loader.gif']}" />` Not sure how would I use this if I need to load it from css.

Comment: Take a look at the resulting HTML (use Firebug or an equivalent browser developer tool) and you will see that that code is creating a URL. If you are using a URL that looks exactly the same in your CSS, then it is no different. That is why I suggest you are attacking the wrong problem: CSS is perfectly viable, valid solution, but you have to have the path to the image correct or it won't work. Using an image tag is fine, too, but don't walk way thinking the problem is CSS... it is not having the correct path to the image that is the problem. If that's easier to get with the tag, go for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I see, the image should be placed in the center of the screen. This could be done by using an outer div for background and center the image inside it.

Add both `div` and `img` tag to the end of the `body` tag so:

```
    <div class="footer">Some Value Here</div>
    <div id="overlay" style="display: none; position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: lightgray; opacity: 0.4; ">
        <img src="page-loader.gif" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto;" />
    </div>
</body>
```

The `style` attribute can be moved to a separate css file and replaced by the `class` attribute.

The `$(document).ready` code can be reduced so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Execute refresh with interval:
    setInterval(refresh, 1 * 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about your directory structure. I am presuming you are working with Java/JSP spring? and not Javascript!

I believe the Resource folder is one up from the web app folder and web app is your root. Have you tried `url(/img/page-loader.gif)`?

Comment: This is more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: I believe his problem is that he has misunderstood his directory structure and what is his root. I have the same set up and the resources folder is one folder up from webapp which is his root so he cannot use a URL like /testweb/src/main/webapp/img/page-loader.gif it would be /img/page-loader.gif